# Pass TappedEvent to a sibling controll in uwp

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a user control with a bunch of buttons behind a scroll viewer that has a grid with a bunch of rows in it. The first row is empty. The buttons in user control need to respond to tap/click when not obscured by scroll viewer's content. My problem is that the scroll viewer caches the tap event and it is not passed to the user control because it is a sibling to the scroll viewer. I would like to somehow pass/propagate the tap event to the user control to get the buttons working. I can't find a good solution to this issue because there seems to be no RaiseEvent(e) method on UI elements in uwp. Due to specific requirements, the whole page needs to react to scroll and the buttons are required to be behind the scroll viewer content. Does anyone know if it is possible to pass the whole event to another element or somehow allow for both controls to handle it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, do you mean to let the `ScrollViewer.Tapped` event pass outside the `UserControl`?

Comment: What I want is for the user control to also receive touch/mouse input, specifically the  Tapped event. Right now only the scrollviewer receives the touch/mouse-related events because it is on top of the usercontrol (both are in the same grid container). I want the scrolling events to work and the scrollviewer's children control's to be able to react to touch/mouse input, but if the user clicks on the button that is visible behind the scrollviewer and is part of aforementioned user control it should also react. Right now it does not work because the scrollviewer eats all the touch/mouse events

Comment: Hello, If your `ScrollViewer` covers the `UserControl`, the pointer cannot click on the content in the `UserControl` because the `ScrollViewer` cannot be penetrated. So please avoid the `ScrollViewer` blocking the operation area, or try to put the content that needs to be operated in the `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: Hello, I know that. If I could do it like that, life would be easy. Unfortunately, it is not up to me how the application should look and behave. I need to handle vertical scroll on the whole page and have static(unmoving) buttons that are behind the scroll viewer content. If I put the buttons(user control) in the scrollviewer the user control will move with the content. I guess I could detect the tap on the scrollviewer and calculate by tap position if the buttons were tapped, but I really don't want to do that. I'm hoping that there is an easier solution that maybe I'm missing.

Comment: Hello, I got it. As you said, judging by pointer position is not a good solution. But `ScrollViewer` encapsulates the Pointer event in response to some gestures and other operations, which will intercept the pointer event triggered on the ScrollViewer. You can try to establish a trigger mechanism (button or shortcut key), after triggering, adjust UserControl to the upper layer of ScrollViewer, and then resume after completing the operation